# Flutter : how to repeat notification endlessly until user sees it

Tags: flutter, notifications, repeat

I want to send notification until the user sees it. I know there are daily weekly repeats but I don't know if there is a way to keep sending notifs until the user clicks the alarm.

I looked at awesome_notification and flutter_local_notifications but don't think they also implemented it..?

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Q: Don't you think users might find that a bit ... annoying?  Q:  How often did you want to "repeat"?  Daily?  Weekly?  Every minute?  Q: Where do you keep "state" (i.e. whether you need to repeat, or if the user already responded)?  Firebase?  Elsewhere?

Comment: @paulsm4 it is intended to behave like that only for important alarms (like fire happening) / I want to repeat it every minute if possible / I am using Firebase and want to keep it there!

Comment: why dont add add a custom sound for notification in order to get the attention of the user or vibrate it.

Comment: @ArbiterChil yes I thought about that too, but worried that the user might not be able to see it right at the moment. I want it to behave like the alarms in our phones.. like ring for a minute and then slient for 3 min .. something like that

Comment: hmmmmm try background fetch package to do on background to force open the app or something will run the app like an alarm.

Comment: @ArbiterChil oh okay thanks for your comment!!